# Using another class scope in existing scope Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to use the scope of another class in the scope of the first class

so instead of

```
scope :active, -> {includes(:b).where(b: {column: 'ACTIVE'}).where(a: {column2: 'ACTIVE'})}
```

I want to be able to use a scope of b

```
scope :active, -> {includes(b.active).where(a: {column2: 'Active'})}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `merge` ( http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge )?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge):

```
scope :active, -> { includes(:b).merge(B.active)
                                .where(a: {column2: 'Active'}) }
```

Note: I used `B` to represent the model class for the `b` column or object.

Or, assuming you're in `a`'s model already:

```
scope :active, -> { includes(:b).merge(B.active)
                                .where(column2: 'Active') }
```

Also, if you WANT eager loading then using `includes` is great. Otherwise, it's faster and less overhead to use `joins`, like this:

```
scope :active, -> { joins(:b).merge(B.active)
                             .where(column2: 'Active') }
```

Comment: this might work, but when I tried it i got the following exception:

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedConnectionException: "DESC b" failed; does it exist?

When I tried DESC b in my sql editor, it worked fine

Comment: Updated answer. Had to make the `includes()` and `joins()` methods receive symbols instead of objects.

Comment: still doesn't answer my desc issue though

Comment: Sorry, I've never used an Oracle backend before. Does the scope itself work? e.g. `B.active` -- does this work in the console?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use scope on model, if it's admin specific, then can separate it to concern
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

```
module AdminUserScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :admin_scope1, -> { includes(:b).where(b: {column: 'ACTIVE'}).where(a: {column2: 'ACTIVE'}) }
    scope :admin_scope2, -> { admin_scope1.where(a: {column2: 'Active'}) }
  end
end

# in your model

include AdminUserScopes

# in active_admin

scope :active, -> { admin_scope1 }
scope :active2, -> { admin_scope2 }
```

Upd:

If you want to use one condition to other model then can use `merge`

```
Dog.all.merge(User.males) # => select * from dogs where sex = 1;
```

If you want to use in association filtering, then:

```
Post.where(user: User.males) # => select * from posts where user_id in (select users.id from users where sex = 1)
```

In your case I guess you have `A` and `B`, and you want to get active A-records what connected  to active B-records

```
# in A
scope :active, -> { where(column: 'ACTIVE') }

# in B
scope :active, -> { where(column2: 'ACTIVE', a: A.active) }

# in somewhere else
scope :active, -> { where(a: A.active) } # => have active A which have active B
```

p.s. it's much easier with more informative names, "A's" and "B's" are hard :)

Comment: this does not answer the question.. I want to use the scope of another class in the existing query to reduce duplication